# How do I merge these two regexs into a single one?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm using this one to remove all whitespace:

```
%s/\s\+//g
```

And this one to wrap comma-separated words between double quotes (and leave one space after the comma):

```
%s/\s*\([^,]\+\)/ "\1"/g
```

I tried merging them like this:

```
%s/\s\+//\|/\s*\([^,]\+\)/ "\1"/g
```

But I get a `Trailing Characters` error.

How to correctly merge those two regexs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the replacement part is different, you'd have to use a `:help sub-replace-expression` to differentiate between the two regexp parts and either remove or double-quote, like this:

```
:%s/\s\+\|\s*\([^,]\+\)/\=empty(submatch(1)) ? '' : ' "'.submatch(1).'"'/g
```

But that still doesn't make sense, because the deletion of the trailing whitespace would come only after it's already been double-quoted. As these two substitutions aren't related, you should really just concatenate the two commands with the `|` command separator (in a mapping, you'd use `<Bar>` instead):

```
:%s/\s\+//g|%s/\s*\([^,]\+\)/ "\1"/g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't merge the two regex into one because the replace part is different.

You could combine the two commands by using `|`.

Try:

```
%s/\s\+//g|%s/\s*\([^,]\+\)/ "\1"/g
```

Comment: References:  `:help /\|` for combining regular expressions and `:help :|` for combining Ex commands.

Answer (score 2):

You Ca use (|) Or Symbol

Try this regex

```
%s/\s\+//g|%s/\s*\([^,]\+\)/ "\1"/g
```

Comment: You're mixing the original Vim- with PCRE-regexp syntax in your answer. That won't work anywhere.